# Multiselection radiobuttons / Checkbuttons["indicatoron"]=False

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two groups of radiobuttons on my tkinter interface :

1) Average - Median Value ...

2) Monthly - Weekly ...

[image: Current interface]

I would like to add a multiselection group of widgets BUT I would like it to have the same aspect of both previous groups.

- The first idea I had was to create a group of radiobuttons and choose any multiselection mode but this mode seems not to exist.
- The second idea was to use a group of checkbuttons and set indicatoron on False but this option doesn't exist on checkbuttons.

Did I miss anything which could solve my problem? Or is there any other possibility that I have not yet considered?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper choice is to use checkbuttons, which are explicitly designed for multiple selections. Contrary to what you wrote in your question, checkbuttons do indeed include an `indicatoron` option.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

vars = {}
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10, pady=10)
for color in ("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"):
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(frame, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                                 text=color, indicatoron=False,
                                 width=6)
    checkbutton.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of checkbuttons with indicatoroff set to true]

Comment: Oh, i don't even know how I missed it